# Parameter Invalid when creating image from stream for ico files having color depth 24 bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

**What I did:**
Trying to create image from a uploaded file using Telerik RadUpload control

```
Dim lImage As Drawing.Image = Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload.UploadedFiles(0).InputStream)
```

**What is wrong:**
From my development machine I could upload any file of type .ico but it is throwing exception on production server:  `System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload.UploadedFiles(0).InputStream)` for particular ico (I would have attached the file but SO is not allowing .ico extension files)

I could not really debug the issue as it is working on my development machine (Windows 7). Any suggestions on why the issue on production server and what I should try? Again, I can't reproduce the issue on my machine.

**Update I:** I could upload other ico files on production. The problem is with ico created using tools like Irfan View Image or Ico FX . Testing team used these tools to create ico files with 24 bit color depth and having problem in uploading them. Development machine has .net framework 4.5 where as production has 4.0

**Update II:** The specific icons that are causing problems have 24 bit color depth. 1 bit, 4 bit, 8 bit, 32 bit work with out any issue.

Comment: What is the image format?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, its .ico